# Highlight roads that are within a buffer or overlapping buffer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

So I have points with a mile buffer. Is there a way to "highlight" the roads that fall under the mile buffer? My original plan is to clip the roads with the buffer, but this will take some time because I have a lot of facilities. I was wondering if there's another tool in the Arctoolbox I can maybe use to speed the process. I can only use tools that come with ArcGIS and I'm on version 10.2. I guess I can also write a python script for my original plan.

Comment: Can you identify what you mean by "highlight". Are you looking at selecting them, do analysis on them, or outputting them to a new layer?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `Select by location` tool (located in the menu bar under "Selection"). You therefore use the buffered points as the `"source layer"` and the road as the `"target layer"`. For the spatial selection method you could probably try `"Intersect the source layer feature"`, but that depends on your needs. After you receive your selection, right click your roads layer and export your selection if needed.

[image: select_by_location]

---

You could use this in an arcpy script (check your ArcGIS Desktop Help for syntax), but there's no need.